# VBA Web-scraping - can't find/fire onchange event for date input field

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am working on a work website that has a date input field and a results table based on the date entered into that field.  It also has a link to a calendar date-picker, which I don't use. When a date is entered manually, the results table  changes dynamically.  It changes immediately after entering the new date so I tried to find an onchange event that I could fire after changing the date field.  I cannot find this event but I did find some javascript on the same page which seems to be related to the date entered into the field.

How do I automate this onchange behaviour without an onchange event in the html?

EDIT: In response to Zwenn and others wondering about the VBA I have used: I don't have any for this part of my macro because there is no onchange event for me to trigger.  I have only tried changing the field value with:

```
iedoc.document.all.radUpToDatePicker.value = strFormattedDateValue
iedoc.document.all.radUpToDatePicker_dateInput.value = strDateVAlue
```

As I mentioned in the other question (which I tried to simplify by re-asking here), this works to change the values but doesn't result in a change of the underlying table as what happens when entered manually.

The HTML behind the date field:

```html
<td>
  <div id="radUpToDatePicker_wrapper" class="RadPicker RadPicker_Default" style="display:inline-block;width:160px;">
    <!-- 2012.3.1016.40 --><input style="visibility:hidden;display:block;float:right;margin:0 0 -1px -1px;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;border:0;padding:0;" id="radUpToDatePicker" name="radUpToDatePicker" type="text" class="rdfd_" value="2020-06-16" title="Visually hidden input created for functionality purposes." />
    <table cellspacing="0" class="rcTable rcSingle" summary="Table holding date picker control for selection of dates." style="width:100%;">
      <caption style="display:none;"> RadDatePicker </caption>
      <tr>
        <td class="rcInputCell" style="width:100%;"><span id="radUpToDatePicker_dateInput_wrapper" class="riSingle RadInput RadInput_Default" style="display:block;width:100%;"><input id="radUpToDatePicker_dateInput" name="radUpToDatePicker$dateInput" class="riTextBox riEnabled" value="16/06/2020" type="text" /><input id="radUpToDatePicker_dateInput_ClientState" name="radUpToDatePicker_dateInput_ClientState" type="hidden" /></span></td>
        <td><a title="Open the calendar popup." href="#" id="radUpToDatePicker_popupButton" class="rcCalPopup">Open the calendar popup.</a>
          <div id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_wrapper" style="display: none">
            <table id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar" summary="Calendar control which enables the selection of dates." cellspacing="0" class="RadCalendar RadCalendar_Default" border="0">
              <caption>
                <span style='display:none;'>Calendar</span>
              </caption>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td class="rcTitlebar">
                    <table cellspacing="0" summary="Title and navigation which can change and show the current year and month." border="0">
                      <caption>
                        <span style='display:none;'>Title and navigation</span>
                      </caption>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col"></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td><a id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_FNP" class="rcFastPrev" title="&lt;&lt;" href="#">&lt;&lt;</a></td>
                          <td><a id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_NP" class="rcPrev" title="&lt;" href="#">&lt;</a></td>
                          <td id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Title" class="rcTitle">June 2020</td>
                          <td><a id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_NN" class="rcNext" title=">" href="#">&gt;</a></td>
                          <td><a id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_FNN" class="rcFastNext" title=">>" href="#">&gt;&gt;</a></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="rcMain">
                    <table id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top" class="rcMainTable" cellspacing="0" summary="Table containing all dates for the currently selected month." border="0">
                      <caption>
                        <span style='display:none;'>June 2020</span>
                      </caption>
                      <thead>
                        <tr class="rcWeek">
                          <th class="rcViewSel" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_cs_1" title="Monday" scope="col" abbr="Mon">M</th>
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_cs_2" title="Tuesday" scope="col" abbr="Tue">T</th>
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_cs_3" title="Wednesday" scope="col" abbr="Wed">W</th>
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_cs_4" title="Thursday" scope="col" abbr="Thu">T</th>
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_cs_5" title="Friday" scope="col" abbr="Fri">F</th>
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_cs_6" title="Saturday" scope="col" abbr="Sat">S</th>
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_cs_7" title="Sunday" scope="col" abbr="Sun">S</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr class="rcRow">
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_rs_1" scope="row">22</th>
                          <td class="rcOtherMonth" title="Monday, May 25, 2020"><a href="#">25</a></td>
                          <td class="rcOtherMonth" title="Tuesday, May 26, 2020"><a href="#">26</a></td>
                          <td class="rcOtherMonth" title="Wednesday, May 27, 2020"><a href="#">27</a></td>
                          <td class="rcOtherMonth" title="Thursday, May 28, 2020"><a href="#">28</a></td>
                          <td class="rcOtherMonth" title="Friday, May 29, 2020"><a href="#">29</a></td>
                          <td class="rcOtherMonth" title="Saturday, May 30, 2020"><a href="#">30</a></td>
                          <td class="rcOtherMonth" title="Sunday, May 31, 2020"><a href="#">31</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="rcRow">
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_rs_2" scope="row">23</th>
                          <td title="Monday, June 01, 2020"><a href="#">1</a></td>
                          <td title="Tuesday, June 02, 2020"><a href="#">2</a></td>
                          <td title="Wednesday, June 03, 2020"><a href="#">3</a></td>
                          <td title="Thursday, June 04, 2020"><a href="#">4</a></td>
                          <td title="Friday, June 05, 2020"><a href="#">5</a></td>
                          <td class="rcWeekend" title="Saturday, June 06, 2020"><a href="#">6</a></td>
                          <td class="rcWeekend" title="Sunday, June 07, 2020"><a href="#">7</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="rcRow">
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_rs_3" scope="row">24</th>
                          <td title="Monday, June 08, 2020"><a href="#">8</a></td>
                          <td title="Tuesday, June 09, 2020"><a href="#">9</a></td>
                          <td title="Wednesday, June 10, 2020"><a href="#">10</a></td>
                          <td title="Thursday, June 11, 2020"><a href="#">11</a></td>
                          <td title="Friday, June 12, 2020"><a href="#">12</a></td>
                          <td class="rcWeekend" title="Saturday, June 13, 2020"><a href="#">13</a></td>
                          <td class="rcWeekend" title="Sunday, June 14, 2020"><a href="#">14</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="rcRow">
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_rs_4" scope="row">25</th>
                          <td title="Monday, June 15, 2020"><a href="#">15</a></td>
                          <td title="Tuesday, June 16, 2020"><a href="#">16</a></td>
                          <td title="Wednesday, June 17, 2020"><a href="#">17</a></td>
                          <td title="Thursday, June 18, 2020"><a href="#">18</a></td>
                          <td title="Friday, June 19, 2020"><a href="#">19</a></td>
                          <td class="rcWeekend" title="Saturday, June 20, 2020"><a href="#">20</a></td>
                          <td class="rcWeekend" title="Sunday, June 21, 2020"><a href="#">21</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="rcRow">
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_rs_5" scope="row">26</th>
                          <td title="Monday, June 22, 2020"><a href="#">22</a></td>
                          <td title="Tuesday, June 23, 2020"><a href="#">23</a></td>
                          <td title="Wednesday, June 24, 2020"><a href="#">24</a></td>
                          <td title="Thursday, June 25, 2020"><a href="#">25</a></td>
                          <td title="Friday, June 26, 2020"><a href="#">26</a></td>
                          <td class="rcWeekend" title="Saturday, June 27, 2020"><a href="#">27</a></td>
                          <td class="rcWeekend" title="Sunday, June 28, 2020"><a href="#">28</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="rcRow">
                          <th id="radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top_rs_6" scope="row">27</th>
                          <td title="Monday, June 29, 2020"><a href="#">29</a></td>
                          <td title="Tuesday, June 30, 2020"><a href="#">30</a></td>
                          <td class="rcOtherMonth" title="Wednesday, July 01, 2020"><a href="#">1</a></td>
                          <td class="rcOtherMonth" title="Thursday, July 02, 2020"><a href="#">2</a></td>
                          <td class="rcOtherMonth" title="Friday, July 03, 2020"><a href="#">3</a></td>
                          <td class="rcOtherMonth" title="Saturday, July 04, 2020"><a href="#">4</a></td>
                          <td class="rcOtherMonth" title="Sunday, July 05, 2020"><a href="#">5</a></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
```

The javascript I found which has something to do with this (as it references the date), but which I can't figure out.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Telerik.Web.UI.RadDateInput, {
      "_displayText": "16/06/2020",
      "_focused": false,
      "_initialValueAsText": "2020-06-16-00-00-00",
      "_postBackEventReferenceScript": "__doPostBack(\u0027radUpToDatePicker\u0027,\u0027\u0027)",
      "_skin": "Default",
      "_validationText": "2020-06-16-00-00-00",
      "autoPostBack": true,
      "clientStateFieldID": "radUpToDatePicker_dateInput_ClientState",
      "dateFormat": "dd/MM/yyyy",
      "dateFormatInfo": {
        "DayNames": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        "MonthNames": ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", ""],
        "AbbreviatedDayNames": ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
        "AbbreviatedMonthNames": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", ""],
        "AMDesignator": "AM",
        "PMDesignator": "PM",
        "DateSeparator": "/",
        "TimeSeparator": ":",
        "FirstDayOfWeek": 1,
        "DateSlots": {
          "Month": 1,
          "Day": 0,
          "Year": 2
        },
        "ShortYearCenturyEnd": 2029,
        "TimeInputOnly": false
      },
      "displayDateFormat": "dd/MM/yyyy",
      "enabled": true,
      "incrementSettings": {
        InterceptArrowKeys: true,
        InterceptMouseWheel: true,
        Step: 1
      },
      "styles": {
        HoveredStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riHover"],
        InvalidStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riError"],
        DisabledStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riDisabled"],
        FocusedStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riFocused"],
        EmptyMessageStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riEmpty"],
        ReadOnlyStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riRead"],
        EnabledStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riEnabled"]
      }
    }, null, null, $get("radUpToDatePicker_dateInput"));
  });
  Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Telerik.Web.UI.RadCalendar, {
      "_DayRenderChangedDays": {},
      "_FormatInfoArray": [
        ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
        ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", ""],
        ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", ""], "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd MMMM yyyy", "HH:mm:ss", "d MMMM", "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss \u0027GMT\u0027", "dd/MM/yyyy", "HH:mm", "yyyy\u0027-\u0027MM\u0027-\u0027dd\u0027T\u0027HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss", "yyyy\u0027-\u0027MM\u0027-\u0027dd HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss\u0027Z\u0027", "MMMM yyyy", "AM", "PM", "/", ":", 1
      ],
      "_ViewRepeatableDays": {},
      "_ViewsHash": {
        "radUpToDatePicker_calendar_Top": [
          [2020, 6, 1], 1
        ]
      },
      "_calendarWeekRule": 2,
      "_culture": "en-GB",
      "_enableKeyboardNavigation": false,
      "_enableViewSelector": false,
      "_firstDayOfWeek": 7,
      "_postBackCall": "__doPostBack(\u0027radUpToDatePicker$calendar\u0027,\u0027@@\u0027)",
      "_rangeSelectionMode": 0,
      "clientStateFieldID": "radUpToDatePicker_calendar_ClientState",
      "enableMultiSelect": false,
      "enabled": true,
      "monthYearNavigationSettings": ["Today", "OK", "Cancel", "Date is out of range.", "False", "True", "300", "1", "300", "1", "False"],
      "skin": "Default",
      "specialDaysArray": [],
      "stylesHash": {
        "DayStyle": ["", ""],
        "CalendarTableStyle": ["", "rcMainTable"],
        "OtherMonthDayStyle": ["", "rcOtherMonth"],
        "TitleStyle": ["", ""],
        "SelectedDayStyle": ["", "rcSelected"],
        "SelectorStyle": ["", ""],
        "DisabledDayStyle": ["", "rcDisabled"],
        "OutOfRangeDayStyle": ["", "rcOutOfRange"],
        "WeekendDayStyle": ["", "rcWeekend"],
        "DayOverStyle": ["", "rcHover"],
        "FastNavigationStyle": ["", "RadCalendarMonthView RadCalendarMonthView_Default"],
        "ViewSelectorStyle": ["", "rcViewSel"]
      },
      "useColumnHeadersAsSelectors": false,
      "useRowHeadersAsSelectors": false
    }, null, null, $get("radUpToDatePicker_calendar"));
  });
  Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Telerik.Web.UI.RadDatePicker, {
      "_PopupButtonSettings": {
        ResolvedImageUrl: "",
        ResolvedHoverImageUrl: ""
      },
      "_animationSettings": {
        ShowAnimationDuration: 300,
        ShowAnimationType: 1,
        HideAnimationDuration: 0,
        HideAnimationType: 1
      },
      "_popupControlID": "radUpToDatePicker_popupButton",
      "clientStateFieldID": "radUpToDatePicker_ClientState",
      "focusedDate": "2020-06-16-00-00-00"
    }, null, {
      "calendar": "radUpToDatePicker_calendar",
      "dateInput": "radUpToDatePicker_dateInput"
    }, $get("radUpToDatePicker"));
  });
  Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Telerik.Web.UI.RadDateInput, {
      "_displayText": "11/06/2020",
      "_focused": false,
      "_initialValueAsText": "2020-06-11-00-00-00",
      "_postBackEventReferenceScript": "__doPostBack(\u0027radFromDatePicker\u0027,\u0027\u0027)",
      "_skin": "Default",
      "_validationText": "2020-06-11-00-00-00",
      "autoPostBack": true,
      "clientStateFieldID": "radFromDatePicker_dateInput_ClientState",
      "dateFormat": "dd/MM/yyyy",
      "dateFormatInfo": {
        "DayNames": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        "MonthNames": ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", ""],
        "AbbreviatedDayNames": ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
        "AbbreviatedMonthNames": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", ""],
        "AMDesignator": "AM",
        "PMDesignator": "PM",
        "DateSeparator": "/",
        "TimeSeparator": ":",
        "FirstDayOfWeek": 1,
        "DateSlots": {
          "Month": 1,
          "Day": 0,
          "Year": 2
        },
        "ShortYearCenturyEnd": 2029,
        "TimeInputOnly": false
      },
      "displayDateFormat": "dd/MM/yyyy",
      "enabled": true,
      "incrementSettings": {
        InterceptArrowKeys: true,
        InterceptMouseWheel: true,
        Step: 1
      },
      "styles": {
        HoveredStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riHover"],
        InvalidStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riError"],
        DisabledStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riDisabled"],
        FocusedStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riFocused"],
        EmptyMessageStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riEmpty"],
        ReadOnlyStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riRead"],
        EnabledStyle: ["width:100%;", "riTextBox riEnabled"]
      }
    }, null, null, $get("radFromDatePicker_dateInput"));
  });
  Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Telerik.Web.UI.RadCalendar, {
      "_DayRenderChangedDays": {},
      "_FormatInfoArray": [
        ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
        ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", ""],
        ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", ""], "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd MMMM yyyy", "HH:mm:ss", "d MMMM", "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss \u0027GMT\u0027", "dd/MM/yyyy", "HH:mm", "yyyy\u0027-\u0027MM\u0027-\u0027dd\u0027T\u0027HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss", "yyyy\u0027-\u0027MM\u0027-\u0027dd HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss\u0027Z\u0027", "MMMM yyyy", "AM", "PM", "/", ":", 1
      ],
      "_ViewRepeatableDays": {},
      "_ViewsHash": {
        "radFromDatePicker_calendar_Top": [
          [2020, 6, 1], 1
        ]
      },
      "_calendarWeekRule": 2,
      "_culture": "en-GB",
      "_enableKeyboardNavigation": false,
      "_enableViewSelector": false,
      "_firstDayOfWeek": 7,
      "_postBackCall": "__doPostBack(\u0027radFromDatePicker$calendar\u0027,\u0027@@\u0027)",
      "_rangeSelectionMode": 0,
      "clientStateFieldID": "radFromDatePicker_calendar_ClientState",
      "enableMultiSelect": false,
      "enabled": true,
      "monthYearNavigationSettings": ["Today", "OK", "Cancel", "Date is out of range.", "False", "True", "300", "1", "300", "1", "False"],
      "skin": "Default",
      "specialDaysArray": [],
      "stylesHash": {
        "DayStyle": ["", ""],
        "CalendarTableStyle": ["", "rcMainTable"],
        "OtherMonthDayStyle": ["", "rcOtherMonth"],
        "TitleStyle": ["", ""],
        "SelectedDayStyle": ["", "rcSelected"],
        "SelectorStyle": ["", ""],
        "DisabledDayStyle": ["", "rcDisabled"],
        "OutOfRangeDayStyle": ["", "rcOutOfRange"],
        "WeekendDayStyle": ["", "rcWeekend"],
        "DayOverStyle": ["", "rcHover"],
        "FastNavigationStyle": ["", "RadCalendarMonthView RadCalendarMonthView_Default"],
        "ViewSelectorStyle": ["", "rcViewSel"]
      },
      "useColumnHeadersAsSelectors": false,
      "useRowHeadersAsSelectors": false
    }, null, null, $get("radFromDatePicker_calendar"));
  });
  Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Telerik.Web.UI.RadDatePicker, {
      "_PopupButtonSettings": {
        ResolvedImageUrl: "",
        ResolvedHoverImageUrl: ""
      },
      "_animationSettings": {
        ShowAnimationDuration: 300,
        ShowAnimationType: 1,
        HideAnimationDuration: 0,
        HideAnimationType: 1
      },
      "_popupControlID": "radFromDatePicker_popupButton",
      "clientStateFieldID": "radFromDatePicker_ClientState",
      "focusedDate": "2020-06-16-00-00-00"
    }, null, {
      "calendar": "radFromDatePicker_calendar",
      "dateInput": "radFromDatePicker_dateInput"
    }, $get("radFromDatePicker"));
  });
  //]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>

</html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  // telerik controls are not registered on a javascript window.onload, so wait a little while first.
  setTimeout("setRadioButtonState()", 200);
</script>
```

Comment: Like QHarr wrote here, *please add your vba code* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358232/automating-a-dynamic-input-field-that-somehow-resets-itself Belief it, everybody who could solve your problem has read your first posting. But nobody can do anything whithout more information. What have you tryed? What is your code? I think it's no *change* event. I think it's a *keypress* event. How do you look for the used event? Is jQeury used? It makes absolutly no sense to ask a question twice, withot more info.

Comment: Zwenn, thanks for answering.  I edited my question with the VBA code I have tried using.  I know close to nothing about JQuery and javascript, I'm afraid. I found that script by searching the webpage source for the date displayed (i.e. todays date by default)